# Checkbox gets checked and unchecked when user taps at background when checkbox appears at the background

Tags: android

Checkbox gets checked and unchecked when user taps at background when checkbox appears at the background.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya please give  me the answer..

Comment: add some code to your question

Comment: @ Eswar I have solved this issue .thanks for comments.